# If $p \in (\frac{n+r-1}{2},n]$, then $r-1 < p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

Suppose that $n$ and $r$ are positive integers such that $n > 2$ and $r > 1$. 
The claim I want to prove is that if there exists a prime $p \in (\frac{n+r-1}{2},n]$, then $r-1 < p$.

It may be easy, but I can not see. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: If a post answers your question then mark this answer as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

We have:
$$\frac{n+r-1}{2}<n \implies n+r-1<2n \implies r-1<n$$

This shows that the arithmetic mean of $r-1$ and $n$ lies between them:
$$r-1<\frac{n+r-1}{2}<n$$

And now, we have:
$$r-1<\frac{n+r-1}{2}<p \implies r-1<p$$

Answer (score 1):

No need to talk about primes.  Let $n,p,r$ be real numbers.
Suppose
$$
\frac{n+r-1}{2} < p \le n .
$$
Then in particular
$$
\frac{n+r-1}{2} <  2n
\\
n+r-1 < 2n,
\\
r-1 < n
$$
and therefore
$$
2p > n+r-1 > (r-1)+(r-1) = 2(r-1)
\\
p > r-1 .
$$